# How can I get data into a Table in JasperReports?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I can't get data into a table.  I'm using the example in Chapter 14, except that I use a Collection instead of the reports data source.  Calling `JasperFillManager.fillReport()` with the Collection in a `JRBeanCollectionDataSource` doesn't show any of the data, but it creates an empty page for each element of the Collection.

Following [this example](https://www.javaquery.com/2015/11/how-to-fill-jasper-table-using.html) I've switched to sending in the data in a Parameter.  This gives an empty table on page 2 of the report (the example itself works).

My code is below.

IntelliJ complains that the jrxml generated by JasperSoft Studio is invalid.  It says that the  element can't be where it is.  Maybe that has something
to do with it.

How do I get data into a Table in JasperReports?

### Java

```java
public class JasperReportsLineItemTableExample {

    public static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JasperReportsLineItemTableExample.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String reportJrxmlFile = "LineItems_Table_A4.jrxml";
        String outputFile = "LineItemsTableExample.pdf";

        List<LineItem> items = LineItemsUtil.createItems(10);
        logger.info(items.size() + " items");
        JRBeanCollectionDataSource itemsJRBean = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(items);

        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        parameters.put("LineItemDataSource", itemsJRBean);


        try {
            JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportJrxmlFile);
//            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, itemsJRBean);
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());

            try (OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(outputFile))) {
                JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, outputStream);

                System.out.println("File Generated");

            } catch (IOException | JRException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (JRException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

### JRXML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.6.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.6.0  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="LineItems_Table_A4" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="NoDataSection" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="565ea393-c6d0-4128-8564-05701d3de374">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <style name="Table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="Dataset1" uuid="57478514-4d8c-49d7-a6e5-8566d1ec7332">
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="itemNumber" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[itemNumber]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="quantity" class="java.lang.Integer">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[quantity]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="unitCost" class="java.lang.Float">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[unitCost]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="totalCost" class="java.lang.Float">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[totalCost]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="LineItemDataSource" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="260" y="34" width="100" height="30" uuid="096a5061-5710-4597-9ce7-e4a7edbfe155"/>
                <text><![CDATA[LineItems Table]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="61" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="357" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="60" y="110" width="440" height="200" uuid="657ac0a8-31c5-4336-8e8d-fdec5dc92bd6">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.table_header" value="Table_TH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.column_header" value="Table_CH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.detail" value="Table_TD"/>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="Dataset1" uuid="ac1740d4-8a9f-409d-979c-ad8788815312">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{LineItemDataSource} ]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="a4de9f35-c7a8-4d2d-8ea1-339144d7d3d4">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="7ea912f2-e802-4b7a-9ccb-3e7b3762f862"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[itemNumber]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="6e4662e4-9421-4328-8d00-766416414c6d"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{itemNumber}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="d10a0d67-02ea-4153-a799-6b4dbdd69200">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="4ba9a6bc-e6ed-477e-ae2f-0d91b27cd42f"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[quantity]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="366e5229-7cb8-441c-9a2a-82535212f06c"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{quantity}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="266fdaed-4f71-43d5-8515-89604973dcd9">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="50" height="30" uuid="c8bbc714-10b6-4305-bf55-9feb87c32498"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[unitCost]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="9db777d5-428c-4387-8e9b-02aa4422407e"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{unitCost}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="b70c951b-951d-443f-9c21-8acf8b025f64">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="b9b914be-ab50-4e2e-bf52-fca2a891a7de"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[total Cost]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="071819a9-ab97-41df-b2b7-b8e9783dfb4d"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{totalCost}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: There's usually no advantage to compiling the `.jrxml` file each time. Compile, load, and fill the `.jasper` file instead. (This probably won't solve the problem, but will improve performance.) Also, consider using inheritance for styles to eliminate some of the duplication around the line widths and borders.

Comment: I left it as jrxml because I made some manual edits to the jrxml to use Parameters instead of the DataSource, and a couple of other changes to try to make it work. 
 There's no sense optimizing this if I can't get data into the Table.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing objects as the main collection. You must add the field as *root fields*  and not as subdataset fields (see solution 1 below)

### Alternative solutions are:

**1) Object list as main collection**

This is the first solution you chose.

Use data as main data collection and set its fields as root fields, and use them directly in your detail band

No table needed, use columnn header band to display table header and detail band as table content.
A detail band will be displayed for each object in main datasource.
Use this only if you only have one table for the whole report (otherwise consider using subreports)

**2) Object list as a field of the main collection's first item**

Set this field as a root field and put it as the datasource of the table using `new JRBeanCollection(myField)`

**3) Object list as a parameter**

This is the second solution you chose.

There is a caveat here : This only works if you use your data in title band, because if main collection is empty or null, detail band won't be displayed.

### About error in jrxml

I guess this comes from `<![CDATA[]]>`. Xml parser sees it as an unclosed tag, whereas this is interpreted by jasper. I also have those errors on correct code.

Please comment if you need more details.